# Three.js 3D Text Bending

Tags: javascript, three.js, typography

Is this still available in r69? In the process of 'rolling' my own, but before moving forward, want to make sure I have not overlooked any vital documentation or useful libraries...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to make through this [example](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#webgl_modifier_bend). Look at messages in the console.

```
<script src="js/modifiers/BendModifier.js"></script>
var text = "THREE.BendModifier";
var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
    size: 128,
    height: 50,
    curveSegments: 4,
    font: "gentilis",
    weight: "bold",
    style: "normal",
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 2,
    bevelSize: 1,
});


var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x62254a
});
var text3D = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var angle = Math.PI / 6;

var modifier = new THREE.BendModifier();
modifier.set(direction, axis, angle).modify( text3D.geometry );

textGeometry.computeBoundingBox();
var textWidth = textGeometry.boundingBox.max.x - textGeometry.boundingBox.min.x;
text3D.position.set(-0.5 * textWidth, 500, 0);
scene.add(text3D);
```

Comment: This was helpful. Very obscure link there though, how'd you find it?

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to mention that you need to change BendModifier.js according to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492948/7132939
to make it work with newer versions of three.js

BendModifier.js uses THREE.Matrix3.getInverse() which is not working any more.
So you need to change the BendModifier.js to use THREE.Matrix4.getInverse(..) and one other change as mentioned in the answer linked.

And generating text has changed - using a THREE.fontLoader()

Complete working example can be found [following this link](https://playingwithstuff.000webhostapp.com/bend/webgl_modifier_bend_my.html)

[Screenshot of web site - link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaERA.png)

And full answer of the internal link:

There was a change in THREE.js but it is quite easy to adjust the BendModifier.js script. Just change the lines

`var InverseP =  new THREE.Matrix3().getInverse( P );`

and

`newVertices[i] = new THREE.Vector3(); newVertices[i].copy( geometry.vertices[i] ).applyMatrix3( InverseP );`

to Matrix4 in both cases - so they will read:

`var InverseP =  new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse( P );`

and

`newVertices[i] = new THREE.Vector3(); newVertices[i].copy( geometry.vertices[i] ).applyMatrix4( InverseP );`

Just tried it with three.min.81.js and it works fine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14230434)

Comment: The external link is only there as an example - the link to the other stackoverflow answer has the code change that is needed - but I see your point

Comment: Thank God You posted this answer, You made my day :P