# Bending text object in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

There is [this](https://github.com/alexan0308/threejs) repo for [this](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#webgl_modifier_bend) example, which is almost 2 years old, and therefore does not work with the recent releases of the threeJS.

I am having the following error and warnings.

`error: THREE.Matrix3.getInverse no longer takes a Matrix4 argument.`

`warning: THREE.Matrix3.getInverse(): can't invert matrix, determinant is 0`

Not sure if it is due to the error and warnings I am getting but the resulting bending is also not correct ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rFeX.png)).

I tried to change the bending axis but no luck.

How can I modify this libray to work with recent threeJS releases or is there any alternative way to bend the text as shown in the example of aforementioned repo?

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in THREE.js but it is quite easy to adjust the BendModifier.js script.
Just change the lines

`var InverseP =  new THREE.Matrix3().getInverse( P );`

and

`newVertices[i] = new THREE.Vector3(); newVertices[i].copy( geometry.vertices[i] ).applyMatrix3( InverseP );`

to Matrix4 in both cases - so they will read:

`var InverseP =  new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse( P );`

and

`newVertices[i] = new THREE.Vector3(); newVertices[i].copy( geometry.vertices[i] ).applyMatrix4( InverseP );`

Just tried it with three.min.81.js and it works fine.

Comment: Example under [link](https://playingwithstuff.000webhostapp.com/bend/webgl_modifier_bend_my.html)