# Text bending in Three.JS

Tags: text, three.js

How can I bend a text that way in threeJS?

I tried using [MOD3 library](https://github.com/foo123/MOD3). However, couldn't manage to bend the text that way.
Is there any alternative way?

[image: Bended Text]

Comment: I believe this answer has what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/27743360/1980846

Comment: @gaitat, thanks for the reply. However, I tried this before (see my [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063816/bending-text-object-in-threejs) post)  and couldn't manage to make it work. It does actually bend the text. However, I have no control over the bending angle. Probably it was not working properly due to the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the BendModifier.js and you should be able to bend the text any way you want.

Example can be found [here using version 81 of three.js](https://playingwithstuff.000webhostapp.com/bend/webgl_modifier_bend_my.html)

You need to play and figure out the direction and axis vectors.
The red "Bending text" has a direction of -y (down) around the z axis (0,0,1) with an overall bend of 90 degrees (PI/4 = 45 degrees on each side)

Hope it helps