# Bend .glb object in three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js

I use a .glb object and want to bend it. I tried to use the information in [Three.js 3D Text Bending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715947/three-js-3d-text-bending)

So, now it does not work. The Error is:

```
BendModifiers.js:57 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The line is: `for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++)  {`

My Code:

```
glbLoader.load('3d_models/ed-object.glb', function (geometry,) {
   staticObj = geometry.scene.children[0];

   ...

   var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
   var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
   var angle = Math.PI / 6;

   var modifier = new THREE.BendModifier();

   modifier.set(direction, axis, angle).modify( staticObj.geometry );
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: BendModifier looks older, I'm not sure whether it works with newer versions of three.js. There's some discussion in the question you link to, but at minimum you need to do `mesh.geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(mesh.geometry)` for each mesh in the model.

Comment: Thank you @DonMcCurdy this is working so far :) , but now I get the error `THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.`
Perhaps you know what it is...

Comment: I think you'll need to create a demo reproducing the problem; like on Codepen, Glitch, or JSFiddle. Otherwise I can only guess. :)